# Read an hexadecimal number and validate its number of digits in C

Tags: c, hex, printf, scanf

I need to read an hexadecimal number with eight digits in C and I need to validate it. If it has less than eight digits fill with "0". If it has more than eight digits, print a message like "please insert a valid number".

I'm doing something like this:

```
unsigned int number;

printf("\nIntroduzca un número: ");
scanf("%08x", &number);
```

But using "%08x" I can fill with "0" but I can't know if the inserted number has more than eight digits and print the error message.

I thought of reading it as a string but later I need to do bit operations on it and print the result in hexadecimal and binary, so I don't know if it's a good idea read the numbers as strings.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd read a string instead, check for its length, then use `strtol` with base 16 to convert it to hex. Note: `strtol` allows for an optional preceeding `0x`, so you may want make sure that the string doesn't start with that. You could also check that the number isn't larger than `ffffffff`.

Comment: Use `sprintf` to convert the number (back) to string, padding it with 0's where necessary.

Comment: `*printf` uses `%0nx` where n is the (nonzero) width to mean pad with zeros instead of spaces but `*scanf` has no such special meaning for `%0nx`; `%08x` means parse _up to_ 8 characters in hex as an `unsigned int` just the same as `%8x`. (Also note that on some systems `unsigned int` isn't 32 bits, but you are unlikely to encounter them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rarely is `scanf()` the best choice to user input.  Better to use `fgets()` to read a line and then additional code to parse the string.

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  // code read the text input into a string, now do something with it.
```

Code is looking for eight hexadecimal digits and OP is on the right track with `scanf("%08x"...`.  `0` is not needed here, just `8` will do to limit the input to 8 digits.  Use `" "` to skip any optional white space.  Use `"%n"` to record the number of characters parsed.

```
  unsigned number = 0;
  int n = 0;
  // If any length (up to 8) hex text was found ...
  // ... and test if `buf[n]` is the end of the string or maybe that 9 digit?
  if (sscanf(buf, "%8x %n", &number, &n) == 1) && buf[n] == '\0') {
    printf("Success :%08x\n", number);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "please insert a valid number\n");
  }
}
```

---

If code needs to insure text did not contain a leading like `"0x123"`, more work is needed.  Various approaches.

Sticking with `*scanf()` specifiers, use `"%*[0123456789abcdefABCDEF]"` to scan a string for hex digits.  The `*` means to not save, just scan.

```
  int n = 0;
  // If any length (up to 8) hex text was found ...
  // ... and test if `buf[n]` is the end of the string or maybe that 9 digit?
  sscanf(buf, "%*8[0123456789abcdefABCDEF] %n", &n);
  if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') {
    unsigned long number = strtoul(buf, NULL, 16);
    printf("Success :%08lx\n", number);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "please insert a valid number\n");
  }
}
```

---

A *clever* way is to avoid `*scanf()` all together and prepend a `"0x"` to the string to be parsed and use `strtol()` only for parsing.

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(&buf[2], sizeof buf - 2, stdin)) {
  char *endptr;
  buf[0] = '0';
  buf[1] = 'x';
  unsigned long number = strtoul(buf, &endptr, 16);
  int length = (int) (endptr - buf);
  if (length < 3 || length > (2 + 8) || *endptr != '\n') {
    fprintf(stderr, "please insert a valid number\n");
  } else {
    printf("Success :%08lx\n", number);
  }
}
```

Comment: The _clever_ trick in the last part utilizes `strtoul(...,...,16)` and `sscanf(..., "%x",...)` allow an optional leading `"0x"`.  By pre-pending the string with `"0x"` and then parse that string, user input like `"0x123"` would get parsed as `"0x0x123"`.  Then the stopping parse location would not be the end of the string.

Comment: You were rigth, I decided to use fgets() to read the line and validate it, and strtol() to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Read it as a string. Check the first 2 bytes to make sure that they didn't add a *0x* to the beginning. Use `strlen` to verify the length.

Then as @Evert said, use `strtol` to convert it to a hex value, using the base 16. Check the return value of `strtol` to verify success  or failure - valid hex number entered or not.